# Python 3 HTTP server image encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I'm currently testing out running other code and files from a Python 3.4 HTTP server. All html and javascript loads perfectly apart from any non-text files. I presume this is due to a lack of encoding on the image files.

Here is the python code I'm using with ip and port removed:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import subprocess

# HTTPRequestHandler class
class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

  # GET
  def do_GET(self):
    # Send response status code
    self.send_response(200)
    # Attempt To Send Different Files
    if self.path.startswith("/favicon.ico"):
      self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
      self.end_headers()
      return
    # HTML
    elif self.path=="/":
      self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
      self.end_headers()
      f = open(curdir + sep + "/Web.html")
      self.wfile.write(bytes(f.read(), "utf8"))
    # Image
    elif self.path=="/files/picture.png":
      self.send_header('Content-type','image/png')
      self.end_headers()
      f = open((curdir + sep + "/files/picture.png"), "rb")
      self.wfile.write(f.read())
    f.close()
    return

def run():
  print('starting server...')

  # Server settings
  server_address = ("LHOST", "LPORT")
  httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
  print('running server...')
  httpd.serve_forever()


run()
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
<title> PAGE 1 </title>
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<img src="files/picture.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Image loads locally just not over the internet. All other HTML works over the web (i.e. port forwarding is not an issue)**

Quite a lot of the research I've done leads to python 2 or simplehttpserver
This is mostly not my code so I'm not entirely sure how it works but the image bit was just a guess I made and it didn't work.

```
# Image
elif self.path=="/files/picture.png":
  self.send_header('Content-type','image/png')
  self.end_headers()
  f = open((curdir + sep + "/files/picture.png"), "rb")
  self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

Thanks for any help

**EDIT: For almost now reason it now occasionally works perfectly**

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for errors?
In Chrome, for example, press F12 and click on "Console".

Comment: For some reason trying it today it now sends sporadically and no there was previously no console errors EDIT: having changed absolutely nothing it now works perfectly

Comment: Have you tried saving the image, or just opening the image's URL directly? What kind of errors do you see? Did you look at the server's console? I suppose that `open(..., "rb")` should be enough for opening the input as a binary. I'm not so  sure about e.g. the correct path to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the answer. but you're doing f.close outside the if. but f is not being defined for the favicon. so if anything tries to access that it might crash.